# .htacess to redirect main domain but not redirect a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to be able to use an .htacess file to allow the main domain only to be redirected, but not a subfolder of that domain.

Example; somesite.com redirects to something.somesite.com
but allow somesite.com/example through to what is in the /example directory.

I did see a question similar to this one but could not understand the answer well enough to want to use the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in `somesite.com`'s document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://something.somesite.com/
```

Of if you'd rather use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} somesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://something.somesite.com/ [L,R=301]
```